# Javascript variable stays undefined

Tags: javascript, division

I have a problem with this script, something is going wrong. 
Rnumer stays undefined.This script should return and write all uneven digits from the random number list. Can someone tell me what I do wrong. Thanks in advance

```
var Rnumber = new Array();

for (i = 0; i<= 100;i++)
{
    Rnumber[i] = Math.ceil(Math.random()*101);
//  document.write(Rnumber[i] + "<br/>");
}

function unevenAndDivisible(Rnumber)
{
    var remainder = new Array();    

    for (i = 0; i<= 100; i++)
    {
        remainder = parseInt(Rnumber[i])%2;
    }
    return remainder;
}

document.write(unevenAndDivisible());
```

Changed to

```
var Rnumber = new Array();

for (i = 0; i<= 100;i++)
{
    Rnumber[i] = Math.ceil(Math.random()*101);
//  document.write(Rnumber[i] + "<br/>");
}

function unevenAndDivisible(Rnumber)
{
    var remainder = new Array();

    for (i = 0; i<= 100; i++)
    {
        remainder[i] = Rnumber[i]%2;
    }
    return remainder;
}
document.write(unevenAndDivisible(Rnumber));
```

but now i get the result :
0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1....

I simply want maybe I asked it wrong the first time, to write al uneven numbers from the random list of Rnumbers
Then I need to divide that through 7 and return that.

**EDIT**

Allmost all problems are clear , thanks everyone for that.
Their is still one question left:
In this code below it only take the first uneven value from remainder and I want that it takes all values that are uneven to the next if statement to check %7.
 Maybe you see the problem better if you run it for youreself

```
var Rnumber = new Array();

for (i = 0; i<= 100;i++)
{
    Rnumber[i] = Math.ceil(Math.random()*101);
}

function unevenAndDivisible()
{
    var remainder = [];
    var answer = [];
    for (i = 0; i<= 100; i++)
    {
        if (Rnumber[i]%2 !== 0)
        {
            remainder.push(Rnumber[i]); 

            for (c = 0; c <= remainder.length;c++)
            {
                if (remainder[c]%7 == 0)
                {
                    answer.push(remainder[c]);
                }
            }           
        }
    }
    return answer;
}

answer = unevenAndDivisible();
document.write(answer);
```

***Problem solved , Thanks everyone***

Comment: Your `Rnumber` [is being set perfectly well](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tkttD/) (in Chromium 14/Ubuntu 11.04), but you seem not to be passing an expected argument to `unevenAndDivisible()`, which is likely the problem. **Edit** what are you trying to achieve with the function call? Evaluate the remainder of *all* numbers, or just *one* number..? Something else?

Comment: I edit my question , maybe its more clearly now

Comment: If you have a quick look at my answer, I think it *should* do as you're wanting...

Comment: Thanks David Thomas ! , youre code does the job.(I was afk a few minutes)
only can someone explain what this mean:
var remainder = [];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass `Rnumber` to the function, as it's already available in scope:

```
function unevenAndDivisible()
    {
        var remainder = [];

        for (i = 0; i<= 100; i++)
        {
            if (Rnumber[i]%2 !== 0) {
                remainder.push(Rnumber[i]);
            }

        }
        return remainder;
    }

remainder = unevenAndDivisible();
console.log(remainder);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tkttD/1/).

---

**Edited** in response to question from OP (in comments to *question*, above):

> ...can someone explain what this mean: `var remainder = [];`

Sure, it's array-literal notation, which is equal to: `var remainder = new Array();`, it's just a little more concise, and I prefer to save myself the typing. I get the impression, from [JS Lint](http://jslint.com/), whenever I use `var x = new Array();` therein that the above version is generally preferred (since it complains otherwise), but I don't know why.

Comment: Thanks for that explaining. I edited my question, can you look for an answer?

Comment: The update to your question seems to be a separate/further question in itself. I'd suggest removing it from *this* question, and asking a separate question entirely as regards the new part. But I would suggest linking to this question, to explain the development of the code and to reduce the chance of people mistakenly attempting to close-as-duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Either pass Rnumber to the function `unevenAndDivisible` or omit it from the argument list.  Since it is an argument, it has more local scope than the initial declaration of Rnumber.

Answer (score 0):

1 - you is not defining the `Rnumber` value that's function argument.
2 - in loop, you're defining remainder to divised value of ranumber and is not saving in array; try:

change:

```
remainder = parseInt(Rnumber[i])%2;
```

to

```
remainder[i] = parseInt(Rnumber[i])%2;
```

Comment: Thanks ! , now I can go further

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the line

```
function unevenAndDivisible(Rnumber)
```

You are passing in Rnumber in as an argument, but when you call `unevenAndDivisible()`
you are not passing it it.
Consequently for the body of the function Rnumber is undefined (cause you passed nothing in)

The following snippet is equivalent to what you wrote nad might explain better

```
function unevenAndDivisible(xyz)
{
    var remainder = new Array();    

    for (i = 0; i<= 100; i++)
    {
        remainder = parseInt(xyz[i])%2;
    }
    return remainder;
}
```

then called as

```
unevenAndDivisible(undefined)
```

to fix it remove the argument from the call definition

i.e. define it as

```
function unevenAndDivisible()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [],
    i = 100;

while (i--) {
    var random = Math.random()*i|0;
    if(random % 2)
       array.unshift(random);
}

alert(array);
```